# Excel -complex nested formula to get previous 6 months status

Tags: excel

I have data with 2 columns named "Team" and "Lead Time%". Data is for 8 months.

I need to calculate 3 months rolling average and compare the average numbers with the actual target.

**Step:1**  Calculate average

I did it using the below mentioned :

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C4,C4)<=2,"",AVERAGE(D2:D4)) ( Below is the screen shot for your reference)
```

[image]

**Step:2** Compare the averages with actual target. But the challenge was i have 8 months data and while calculating rolling average i start from 3rd month, hence first two months will be blank for every team.

I wanted to write a simple "IF" formula to check if the team has achieved the target or not. I wrote `=IF(E4="","",IF(E4="","",IF(E4>=F4,1,0))).`

It would have been worked fine if the data is always for 8 months,but some times the data will be for 9 months and i need results only for last/previous six months.

To achieve this i wrote several other conditions.
Condition 1 : `=A2*12+B2` ( Year * Total number of months in a year + Month in the data)

Condition 2 : `=$N$3*12+$M$3` ( Current Year * Total number of months in a year + Current Month)

Condition 3 : `=IF(C2<>C3,B2,"")` ( To identify current month)

`=MAX(L:L)` : Current month

`=MAX(A:A)` : Current Year

`=J2-I2` : To identify Months

Then Finally wrote : `=IF(K4>=6,"",IF(E4="","",IF(E4>=F4,1,0)))`

Now even if the data is for 9 or 10 months it will calculate only for previous six months.

[image]

Please help me in nesting this complex formula or suggesting any other easy way to do it is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying to write a complex excel nested formula to get the status for previous 6 months. Thanks..

Comment: Could you not use the `AVERAGEIFS` function?

Comment: Average is not a problem... To get status column is a challenge... I had to write several conditions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C4,C4)<=2,"",AVERAGE(C4:INDIRECT("d"&MAX(MATCH(C4,C$1:C12,0),ROW(B4)-5))))
```

It averages the values from the current row back a maximum of 6 rows using Match as a way to restrict the average to the correct Team.
[image]

Comment: Hi Clayton, Thanks a ton for your help. I need average for 6 months Hence i had to write Condition 1, 2 and 3 mentioned in the question. I am sorry may be i am not getting it. I don't see any difference between formula i used and your formula. Both are giving the same result. There is slight difference in average calculation as well.

Comment: Please check my formula on your data with more than 8 rows for a given team., Please take a look at row 14 for example, it averages rows 10-14 (5 rows for France). Row 17 averages rows 12-17 (6 rows for France). The formula counts back to the beginning of the group a maximum of 6 rows. The calculation difference is because I didn't use your exact figures and the averages are formatted to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Hi Clayton, Sorry for the delayed response was down with fever. Thanks for the response. I am still not getting the result i want. Don't know how to upload a excel sheet here. Hence edited my question and attached the screen shot in my original post. Please have a look at it... If i 11 months data the average should calculate only for 6 months. The formula you provided and formula i used both calculate average for 9 months and also i have used same numbers, still averages are different. Please check and let me know if you need further calculation.

Comment: You're "Number I want" column are only the average for 3 months (current plus previous 2). For example, in the row for 2016 - 1 - Czech the average you "want" is 16.215473 which is the average for months 11, 12 and 1 (15.443478 + 15.7+17.502941)/3=16.215473. However you asked for the previous 6 month average which is 15.7962 - provided by my formula. Also, if you don't want averages for less than 6 months simply change "<=2" to "<=5".

Comment: Please click the up arrow above if the answer was useful. That indicates to others that they should look at this as well. Thanks!